# YII Inserting Multiple Dynamic rows

Tags: yii

This is my code in view/_form.php

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'ScriptArgumentClassType'; //or whatever field
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($meta,**'[]ScriptArgumentClass_id'**,CHtml::listData(AutoScriptArgumentClass::model()->findAll`enter code here`($criteria),'id','ScriptArgumentClassType'), array('prompt'=>'Please select Argument class type'));
    ?>  
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'TnType'; //or whatever field
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($meta,**'[]Type_id'**,CHtml::listData(AutoTnType::model()->findAll($criteria),'id','TnType'), array('prompt'=>'Please select TN type'));
    ?>
  </td>

  <td>
    <?php
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'service'; //or whatever field
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($meta,'**'[]Service_id'**,CHtml::listData(Service::model()->findAll($criteria),'id','service'), array('prompt'=>'Please select Service'));
    ?>
  </td>

  <td>
    <?php
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'Manufacture'; //or whatever field
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($meta,'**[]Cpe_id'**,CHtml::listData(AutoCPE::model()->findAll($criteria),'id','Manufacture'), array('prompt'=>'Please select CPE'));
    ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

this is a row of 4 columns. Actually I have used the jquery code to get rows inserted dynamically on clicking AddNew. Works Fine. Now I am trying to save it to the database using yii.

```
$metadatas=$_POST['AutoTestScriptMeta'];            
foreach ($metadatas as $metadata ) {
  $meta=new AutoTestScriptMeta;             
  $meta->attributes = $metadata;
  $meta->save(false);
}
```

Here I am doing foreach for inserting multiple rows into one table.
It gets inserted in this way for 2 inputed row values

1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 3 0
0 0 0 2
1 0 0 0
0 3 0 0
0 0 4 0
0 0 0 2

instead of

1 2 3 2
1 3 4 2

instead of inserting 2 rows it inserts 8 rows each with a column value.

See the code in bold (** **). That is how I am declaring it as an array.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you give us a var_dump() / print_r() of the $_POST array to see what is actually being posted?

Comment: This is the print_r                                                                Array ( [ScriptArgumentClass_id] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 ) [Type_id] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 ) [Service_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 ) [Cpe_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )

Comment: The problem is solved I am able to save the records. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite straight forward here..

What is happening is your jquery is making a post request for each attribute or in other words with data of single column in database..Thats why you are getting only one filed set in each metadata variable which corresponds to one post request..

So what you can do is either merge 4-4 requests before saving..or make your jquery submit  all 4 drop down values...

First one code I can do for you,

```
$metadatas=$_POST['AutoTestScriptMeta'];
$iterations=count($metadata)/4;
$clubbed_array=array();
for($i=0;$i<$iterations;$i++)
{
    array_push($clubbed_array,array($metadata[$i*4+0][0],$metadata[$i*4+1][1],$metadata[$i*4+2][2],$metadata[$i*4+3][3]));
}

foreach ($clubbed_array as $clubbed_value ) {
      $meta=new AutoTestScriptMeta;
      $meta->attributes = $clubbed_value;
      $meta->save();
}
```

Comment: just now I have seen your answer. I will let you know

Comment: when I fill in two rows and give vardump it gives this                 array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL } }